# Database RecordSet Matching on Dollar amounts

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table of Debits and a Table of credits. I need to try and match them as closely as possible.

So here is my idea - but I'm not the best with the coding logic... If someone has a better idea please feel free to chime in.

```
Table 1 - Debits
$1.50
$1.33
$2.55
$2.66

Table 2 - Credits
$5.00
$3.55
$1.55
$1.35
$1.33
```

So here is my thought process:

1. Open a recordset for the credits and sort DESCENDING by credit amount.
2. Open a recordset for the debits and sort ASCENDING by debit amount.
3. Move through the debit recordset, one by 1 - because for each debit we need to match a credit that is EQUAL TO or GREATER than the debit amount
4. Move through the credit recordset, one by 1 - this is how we will get to the credit that is equal to or greater than the
5. If the debit amount EQUALS the credit amount, stop and mark that credit amount as taken for that debit. If the debit amount gets to a credit amount that is LARGER than the debit amount, then stop and take that first one that is greater than.

So in the case of my code example above... The debits would take the following credits

```
$1.50 -> $1.55
$1.33 -> $1.33
$2.55 -> $3.55
$2.66 -> $5.00
```

If anyone can help build that code logic it would be greatly appreciated. Unless I'm going about this all wrong and should try something else that MS Access can do...

Comment: SQL would be better, in my opinion. And is there no Primary Key? Just a Double field?

Comment: How would I do it with SQL? I ask because I need to eliminate a credit after it is used. I can add a primary key to the table(s) since this project is still in the works.

Comment: I think you might be taking an incorrect approach. How does the 'system' know when a credit is used? I assume it can be taken care of at that point in time? What is your ultimate goal here? To keep a running tally of how many outstanding Debits there are? Or Credits?

Comment: Basically, a user will import a database (Excel table) into a table. These are the debits that now must have credits assigned to them. This has to do with business related things for balance sheets, so no need for me to get into details - the point simply being that it needs credit amounts that either MATCH or are GREATER than the debits. The debits will be imported by the user each month. The tool will be used to keep a running tally of the debits. Does this help?

Comment: The system or "Tool" that we are making should know that a credit has been used, because once it has been matched to a debit - we will mark it off on the credit table as taken. (Either a boolean, an invoice#, delete it from the table, etc... any of those work).

Comment: I am not trying to overlook your requirement of taking care of the credits, but can't you just use transaction dates for debits/credits and know your 'tally' of debits at any given time, given a start and end date? Sum of all debits - Sum of all credits? Or is this not your main goal? To my understanding, a running tally of debits is the main goal.

Comment: Oh - No, the issue with that is that we will later be categorizing the debits by state and time - those credit amounts need to match exactly EVEN when filtering. If we did SUM amounts, we won't have the categorization necessary for filtering later - in addition, the credits need to be kept up with month-to-month.

Comment: @user2296381 What do you do if you assign a credit that is greater than the debit? For example debit of 5 and credit of 10.  What happens to the extra 5 from the credit?

Comment: Could you approximate how large of a dataset are you running this on? Are we talking about 100s or records in credits and debits or are we talking about 1000s or 10000s?  I'm wondering how worth it is to try a certain method.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out what you need to do.  Your debit table contains a debitID and date, right, and your credit table contains a creditID and date, and then there's a creditDebit table containing one or more debitIDs for each credit?  You haven't mentioned dates, but is there a restriction on credits only applying to past debits?

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a bin packing problem.  Depending on the number of records and how fast you need to solve it will determine the algorithm you can use.  For smaller number of records, you can just brute force it to find the optimal solution.  If its insanely large then a heuristic based algorithm will be better.

Basically what exact implementation will depend on how many combinations of records can be made.  (m credits and n debits means m*n combinations.  I imagine you could easily start optimizing this by removing the exact matches)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem

Edit

The results of a first fit descending.  The nice thing is you can fit more than one debit into one credit if it fits.  Now if you don't want this behavior it is easily modifiable.  Instead of checking if there is enough space left, you simply check if it is used or not.
There are other heuristics you can use, best fit, worst fit, etc.  In this scenario, personally I would most likely try and allocate all the exact matches first, then run this algorithm on the remainder, but as I mentioned in my comment earlier, this is a situation/solution that depends on the data set size.

```
$5.00 -> $2.66, $1.50
$3.55 -> $2.55
$1.55 -> $1.33 

Public Type Record
    ID As Long
    Amount As Currency
    Allocated As Boolean
    AllocatedAmount As Currency
End Type

Public Function PaymentAllocation()
    Dim cr() As Record
    Dim de() As Record
    ' function returns records with amounts in descending order
    cr = QueryToArray("CR", "CR_AMT")
    de = QueryToArray("DE", "DE_AMT")

    ' first fit descending order
    ' starting with largest credit and debit, check if they fit
    ' if fit, then allocate
    ' if not, then check next credit
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = LBound(cr) To UBound(cr)
        For j = LBound(de) To UBound(de)
            If de(j).Allocated = False Then
                If (cr(i).Amount - cr(i).AllocatedAmount) >= de(j).Amount Then
                    de(j).Allocated = True
                    cr(i).AllocatedAmount = cr(i).AllocatedAmount + de(j).Amount
                    Debug.Print cr(i).Amount, de(j).Amount
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Function

Public Function QueryToArray(tableName, fieldName) As Record()
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim ans() As Record
    Dim i As Long
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM " & tableName & " ORDER BY " & tableName & "_AMT DESC;", dbOpenDynaset)
    ReDim ans(1 To DCount(tableName & "_ID", tableName))
    i = 0
    Do Until rs.EOF
        i = i + 1
        ans(i).ID = rs(tableName & "_ID").Value
        ans(i).Amount = rs(fieldName).Value
        ans(i).Allocated = False
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    QueryToArray = ans
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

tblDebits

```
id     amount    credit_id
1      $1.50
2      $1.33
3      $2.55
4      $2.66
```

tblCredits

```
id     amount
1      $5.00
2      $3.55
3      $1.55
4      $1.35
5      $1.33
```

---

Then run the following function from a button or something:

```
Function AssignCredits()

Dim db As Database
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset
Dim blnCreditAssigned As Boolean

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT tblDebits.id, tblDebits.amount, tblDebits.credit_id FROM tblDebits ORDER BY tblDebits.amount ASC")
    Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT tblCredits.id, tblCredits.amount FROM tblCredits ORDER BY tblCredits.amount ASC")

    rs1.MoveFirst
    rs2.MoveFirst

    Do Until rs1.EOF
        Do Until blnCreditAssigned = True Or rs2.EOF
            If rs2![amount] >= rs1![amount] Then
                rs1.Edit
                rs1![credit_id] = rs2![id]
                rs1.Update
                blnCreditAssigned = True
            End If   
            rs2.MoveNext
        Loop
        rs1.MoveNext
        blnCreditAssigned = False
    Loop

    rs1.Close
    rs2.Close
    MsgBox "Credit assignment complete"

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, since you said you had to match a credit to a debit, I assumed that a credit can only be used once. I think you find this code to do the job.

```
Sub CreditMatch()
    Dim rsDebit As Recordset
    Dim rsCredit As Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblDebits ORDER BY Amount"
    Set rsDebit = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    Do
        strSQL = "SELECT * "
        strSQL = strSQL & "FROM tblCredits "
        strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE ID Not In (SELECT CreditID FROM tblDebits) AND Amount >=" & rsDebit("Amount")
        strSQL = strSQL & "  ORDER BY Amount"
        Set rsCredit = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
        If Not rsCredit.EOF Then
            rsDebit.Edit
            rsDebit("CreditID") = rsCredit("ID")
            rsDebit.Update
        End If
        rsDebit.MoveNext
    Loop Until rsDebit.EOF
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This still needs more work but it comes up with the answer you need:

```
select debit_value, min(credit_value) as match_credit_value
from
(
select d.value as debit_value, c.value as credit_value, d.id as did, c.id as cid
from debits d
cross join credits c
where c.value >= d.value and d.id < c.id
) x
group by x.debit_value

+-------------+--------------------+
| debit_value | match_credit_value |
+-------------+--------------------+
| 1.33        | 1.35               |
| 1.5         | 1.55               |
| 2.55        | 3.55               |
| 2.66        | 5                  |
+-------------+--------------------+
```

Data generated using this SQL script:

```
create table debits ( id integer, value money );
insert into debits values (1, 1.33);
insert into debits values (2, 1.50);
insert into debits values (3, 2.55);
insert into debits values (4, 2.66);
create table credits ( id integer, value money );
insert into credits values (1, 1.33);
insert into credits values (2, 1.35);
insert into credits values (3, 1.55);
insert into credits values (4, 3.55);
insert into credits values (5, 5.00);
```

Answer (score 0):

As it seems like you're trying to calculate account balance by matching debits with credits. Here is another approach. At the end you'll have the information which debit is closed with which credits (yes plural). If this is not sth you're looking for please tell.

1. Take one debit $1.50
2. Take one credit $5.00 (doesn't matter the order)
3. if (debit >= credit) debit - credit -=> debitRemainder
   if(debit < credit) credit - debit -=> creditRemainder
4. if debitRemainder is >0 then take this as new debit and goto step 2
5. if creditRemainder is >0 then take this as new credit and goto step 1(jump over step2 while you already have a credit amount)

You have multiple credits/debits matching multiple debits/credits like:

```
debits                 - credits
$1.50 -> $0.00         - ($5.00) $5.00 -> $3.50
$1.33 -> $0.00         - ($5.00) $3.50 -> $2.17
$2.55 -> $0.38         - ($5.00) $2.17 -> $0.00
($2.55) $0.38 -> $0.00 - ($3.55) $3.55 -> $3.17
$2.66 -> $0.00         - ($3.55) $3.17 -> $0.51
no more debits thus account has credit balance:
$0.51 + $1.55 + $1.35 + $1.33
```

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure what you're doing or why (you need dates and a customerID, right?) but if what you want to do is match credits with debits whose differences are minimized, then include the difference (credit-debit >= 0) in your join between credits and debits (on customerID, maybe limited by creditDate >= debitDate), then apply credits to debits in the sequence with descending differences.

I'm assuming you have another table because a credit can apply to more than one debit, or a debit could be paid by more than one credit, but you haven't mentioned that.  Regardless, if I were doing it (and I understand what you're trying to do,) I would start by joining credit and debit amounts so exact matches are taken first.  Then you can exclude those from your iterative checks of credit and debit rows.